# Relativistic probability amplitude of a particle to be in certain position

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, wavefunction, probability, foundations

In the book “The story of spin” by Tomonaga on page 110, it says

> They insisted that a concept like "the probability of a particle to be at $x$ in space" is meaningless for relativistic particles—be they electrons, photons, or Klein-Gordon particles—and therefore it is meaningless to interpret $\psi (x)$ as the probability amplitude.

He is talking about Pauli and Weisskopf ideas on relativistic wave functions.

I would like to understand that argument. Why the concept of "probability of a particle to be at $x$ in space" is meaningless for a relativistic particle? Are those arguments still valid?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is "the probability of a particle to be at $x$
in space" is meaningless for measurements of relativistic particles which are more precise than (roughly) the compton wavelength, for the following reason. If the uncertainty of position of a particle (say, electron) is low, the momentum uncertainty and, therefore, energy uncertainty is high, therefore, besides the initial electron there can be additional electron-positron pairs at (almost) the same position, so you don't really know which electron has that position (I read something like that in a book by Landau). I tend to think this argument is still valid.

Comment: Hmm. But even in the relativistic case, one can do an experiment with a screen and find a particle to be in a particular place. So how to predict such an experiment in QFT?

Comment: Can you point to which book you mean?

Comment: @doublefelix : https://books.google.com/books?id=Tpk-lqyr3GoC&pg=PA1&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false , Introduction, para 1. So it is indeed Course of theoretical physics by Landau and Lifshitz, but Landau is not an author of this volume (Quantum Electrodynamics)

Comment: @doublefelix : One can find a particle in a particular place, but which particle is that? The original one or a particle from an electron-positron pair created in a precise coordinate measurement, which requires high energy? So in QFT one uses, e.g., the Fock space, and the system can contain states with more than one particle.

Comment: To me, the big picture is: we can do position measurements on particles moving at relativistic speeds. They give a definite position on a screen, experimentally. Whether this is the original particle or not can be argued about, but the main point is: how do we predict the distribution of positions seen on the screen? I see nothing ill-defined about this.

Comment: @doublefelix : I m afraid we are talking about different things. Maybe I misunderstood you. You are talking about particles moving at a relativistic speed. So one of these particles hits the screen at a certain place. But how accurately its position is measured in this case? I would say the accuracy is not much better than if the particle had a nonrelativistic speed, as the accuracy is mostly determined by the properties of the screen. What I had in mind was a particle with a speed that can be relativistic or nonrelativistic, but if you measure its coordinate with high (continued)

Comment: @doublefelix : precision, you typically use, say, high-energy photons, and pairs can be created in the course of such measurement.

Comment: It seems like in your answer you are saying that in general, position measurements on relativistic particles are meaningless. So that should include measurements done with screens, like in the double-slit experiment. If your answer does not include screens, then it remains in your answer to explain why a measurement of position on a screen doesn't count as a position measurement.

Comment: @doublefelix : No, that is not what my answer says. It says that probability of a particle being in a certain point is meaningless. So it is not position measurements that are meaningless, but position measurements with high precision (roughly speaking, better than the Compton wavelength).

Comment: If I read your answer without knowing better, I would assume it means that position measurements are not meaningful in relativistic QM. Maybe it could be rephrased to include the part about the compton wavelength?

Comment: @doublefelix : Maybe you're right, but I don't feel I'm going to edit my answer. If you wish, you could edit it or write your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the text in question is quite vague, but there are some issues that come up with relativistic theories.

For instance if something, say $p(x),$ is a probability density, then $\int p(x,t)dx=1.$ But if you have a relativistic theory then you should also be able to compute $\int p(x',t')dx'=1,$ where $x'$ various over a surface of $t'=$ constant for a different inertial frame. And it is generally impossible to have both.

An example where you can't have both is $p(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{(x-vt)^2/2\sigma^2}.$ And it's not just because of the problem that appears when $v=0$ where density is frame dependent because of length contraction. It is the relativity of simultaneity for the case ($v\neq 0$) where when you integrate over a surface of constant $t'$ you can get regions of earlier $t$ to the left and regions of later $t$ to the right, thus integrating to larger than one even after you adjust the for length contraction.

But even in nonrelativistic theory it is generally wrong to assume that there simply is a probability that a particle has preexisting properties with a particular probability. Its a story some people tell and in some situations it won't bite you. But it isn't right and thinking it will get you in trouble.

All you really want is relative frequencies of different interaction outcomes. Since that is what you measure in the lab.

Comment: of course, you can have both. In the other frame $p(x)$ will change with a $\gamma$ factor.

Comment: @Anthonny I edited the answer to include more details so you won't be able to think a gamma factor fixes it the way it would for a delta function probability distribution. There are cases where it can work, but it doesn't work in general.

Comment: *"But even in nonrelativistic theory it is generally wrong to assume that there simply is a probability that a particle has preexisting properties with a particular probability."* Could you explain why that would be wrong?

Comment: @JánLalinský It's wrong because assuming it leads to experimentally falsified predictions. It is meaningless to say something has properties with probabilities if you can't reveal those properties with the right frequencies. But that doesn't happen. What you have instead is something that interacts in certain ways, which is different. If you assume it has a spin, momentum, kinetic energy, position, etc. And that measurements just reveal those properties  preexisting by revealing the preexisting values then it leads to errors. For instance, the correlations in a bell type measurement.

Comment: @JánLalinský You can look at an example of a Stern-Gerlach interaction. If you do it the correct way, you analyze the actual setup in an accurate and continuous manner. And you mathematically see the incoming beam split into two beams and the sizes of the beams are determined by the relative size of the spin's projection onto the eigenspaces and after the beam separates the two beams each have their spin completely polarized. If you spilt the beam first with a spin independent beam splitter then send each part through then different parts end up becoming spin up and spin down.

Comment: @JánLalinský For instance 3/5|+>+4/5|-> has the 64-99 percentile of left-right ends up |+> and 0-63 ends up |->. But if you split the 0-49 and the 50-99 in the left-right percentile first into two beams and then measure the spin then the ones that were originally in the 48th percentile end up being spin up. The spin up measurement does not reveal a preexisting spin of a particle that had a preexisting position. But there are thousands of examples of lack of counterfactual definiteness, hidden variables, and sample samples independent of a maximal algebra of commuting operators.